# Why does my Python bot sometimes posts one time too many?

Tags: python, api, tweepy, praw

I wrote a bot that fetches posts from Reddit and posts them on a Twitter Account. But sometimes - i dont know why - it posts twice in a row, and not once every 3 hours. I am suspecting that it is because i did something like this:

```
do stuff:
    if stuff doesnt already exist:
        do other stuff
    else:
        do stuff
```

And i really think its bad practice, but i cant figure out how else i can let it run in an infinite loop, but still try to get a post that hasnt been posted before.

I have two points in my code where i "re-run" the entire code upon a check. One is when the post that is fetched from reddit is not an image, the other when the post that was fetched was already posted before (and stored in a json file for this exact check).

I hope someone understands what i mean, thanks in advance.

```
import time
import tweepy
import datetime
import praw
import urllib.request
import os
import json


def Mainbot():
    reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='X',
                          client_secret='X',
                          user_agent='RedditFetchBot by FlyingThunder')

    def Tweet(postinfo):
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("X", "X")
        auth.set_access_token("X", "X")
        api = tweepy.API(auth)
        try:
            api.update_with_media("local-filename.jpg", postinfo)
        except:
            print("not a file post")
            Mainbot()            #check 1


    post = reddit.subreddit('okbrudimongo').random()
    x = post.id

    with open('data.json', 'r') as e:
        eread = e.read()
        if x not in eread:
            with open('data.json', 'a') as f:
                json.dump(x, f)
                f.close()
                e.close()
        else:
            e.close()
            print("already posted")
            Mainbot()      #check 2

    print(post.url + " " + post.title)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(post.url, "local-filename.jpg")
    Tweet(postinfo=post.title+" (https://www.reddit.com" + post.permalink+")")
    try:
        time.sleep(5)
        os.remove("local-filename.jpg")
    except:
        print("Datei nicht vorhanden")

def loop():
    time.sleep(1800)
    print("still running")
    print(datetime.datetime.now())

while True:
    Mainbot()
    loop()
    loop()
    loop()
    loop()
    loop()
    loop()
```

By the way, here is what it gives back - i made print checks to see what goes wrong, here you can see what it says when it posts twice

```
still running
2019-09-24 13:27:23.437152
still running
2019-09-24 13:57:23.437595
already posted
https://i.redd.it/xw38s1qrmlh31.jpg Führ Samstag bai ihm
https://i.redd.it/nnaxll9gjwf31.jpg Sorri Mamer
still running
2019-09-24 14:27:39.913651
still running
2019-09-24 14:57:39.913949
still running
2019-09-24 15:27:39.914013
```

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a bit to unpack here.

```py
if x not in eread:
    ...
else:
    ...
    Mainbot()    # <--- this line
```

in the above snippet, you check if the post.id is already in your file. and if it is, you call the function `Mainbot()` again which means it has another chance to post a tweet.

However, this line

```py
Tweet(postinfo=post.title+" (https://www.reddit.com" + post.permalink+")")
```

Occurs outside if your if-else check, which means it will post a tweet regardless of whether or not the post.id was in your file.

I also want to address your method of looping the bot. Your use of recursion is causing your double-posting issue and could technically recursively loop a post many tweets at once if multiple posts in a row end up in the "else" branch listed above.

Also, if you are using `python with open(...) as f:` you don't need to call `python f.close()`

Here is a solution I came up with that should solve your problem and doesn't use recursion:

```py
import time
import tweepy
import datetime
import praw
import urllib.request
import os
import json

def initBot():
# this function logs into your reddit and twitter accounts
# and returns their instances

    reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='XXXX',
                          client_secret='XXXX',
                          user_agent='RedditFetchBot by FlyingThunder')
    auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("XXXX", "XXXX")
    auth.set_access_token("XXXX",
                          "XXXX")
    twitter = tweepy.API(auth)

    return reddit, twitter

def Tweet(post):
# this function simply tries to post a tweet
    postinfo = post.title + " (https://www.reddit.com" + post.permalink + ")"
    try:
        twitter.update_with_media("local-filename.jpg", postinfo)
    except:
        print("not a file post"+post.permalink)

def Mainbot():
    while True:
        with open('data.json', 'r+') as e:  # 'r+' let's you read and write to a file
            eread = e.read()

            # This section loops until it finds a reddit submission
            # that's not in your file
            post = reddit.subreddit('okbrudimongo').random()
            x = post.id
            while x in eread:
                post = reddit.subreddit('okbrudimongo').random()
                x = post.id

            # add the post.id to the file
            json.dump(x, e)
            print(post.url + " " + post.title)

            # Get and tweet image
            urllib.request.urlretrieve(post.url, "local-filename.jpg")
            Tweet(post)

            # Remove image file
            try:
                time.sleep(5)
                os.remove("local-filename.jpg")
            except:
                print("Datei nicht vorhanden")

        # sleep for a total of three hours, but report status every 30 minutes
        for i in range(6):
            time.sleep(1800)
            print("still running")
            print(datetime.datetime.now())

if __name__ == "__main__":

    reddit, twitter = initBot()
    Mainbot()
```

I haven't tested this because I don't have twitter keys.

Answer (score 0):

Solution i found (i still dont fully understand what mechanic caused the bug):

```
import time
import tweepy
import datetime
import praw
import urllib.request
import os
import json


def Mainbot():
    reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='XXXX',
                          client_secret='XXXX',
                          user_agent='RedditFetchBot by FlyingThunder')

    def Tweet(postinfo):
        auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler("XXXX", "XXXX")
        auth.set_access_token("XXXX",
                              "XXXX")
        api = tweepy.API(auth)
        try:
            api.update_with_media("local-filename.jpg", postinfo)
        except:
            print("not a file post"+post.permalink)
            Mainbot()


    post = reddit.subreddit('okbrudimongo').random()
    x = post.id

    with open('data.json', 'r') as e:
        eread = e.read()
        if x not in eread:
            with open('data.json', 'a') as f:
                json.dump(x, f)
                f.close()
                e.close()
                print(post.url + " " + post.title)
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(post.url, "local-filename.jpg")
                Tweet(postinfo=post.title + " (https://www.reddit.com" + post.permalink + ")")
                try:
                    time.sleep(5)
                    os.remove("local-filename.jpg")
                except:
                    print("Datei nicht vorhanden")
        else:
            e.close()
            print("already posted")
            Mainbot()
def loop():
    time.sleep(1800)
    print("still running")
    print(datetime.datetime.now())

while True:
    Mainbot()
    loop()
    loop()
    loop()
    loop()
    loop()
    loop()
```